# Get data from Firebase in Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire

I have written my app with ionic 2 and followed the [tutorial of Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/), but I don't know how I can get a specific element from my firebase database.

For example I have this tree :

```
user

|__ (user_id)

  |_ name : 'toto'
```

And so on...

I tried this way:

```
elt: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
this.elt = af.database.list('/user');
```

But how can I work with the selected data?

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution which is similar than yours :

```
af.database.list('/user', { preserveSnapshot: true})
    .subscribe(snapshots=>{
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                this.items.push({
                id: snapshot.key,
                name: snapshot.val().name
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the data as an array from a provider you need to return a promise which will be returned once the `firebaseListObservable` event is triggered with return data.

In your provider `.ts`

```
getData(fbPath): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.db.list(fbPath).subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    })
  })
}
```

Here the promise resolves once the `data` is populated and returns an array with easy access to the `$value` and `$key` properties. Which is ideal for creating conditionals or complex queries or a provider service with generic properties ( as opposed to querying the snapshot of the `firebaseListObservable` directly )

In your controller you can then write something like

```
 this.providerName.getData('users').then(data => {
    console.log('data',data);
  })
```

This will return an object literal with the values

- $exists
- $key
- $value

So now if you want a match conditional you can loop through the `data` with the match condition on the `$key` of the table `users`

```
if(myUserIdVar === data.$key){ // do something here };
```

A tidier syntax can be found using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) Where for example if you want a condition to match a stored id, say `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` you can do a simple `_.find`

```
 import { find } from 'lodash';
 import * as firebase from 'firebase'; // Or just the firebase auth stuff
 ...

 let filteredUser = find(data, ['$key', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid])
```

The `$key` value will be equal to the `|__ (user_id)` value

Answer (score 1):

I think, `af.database.list('/user')`  returns an Observable. You need to subscribe to it. Like this:

```
af.database.list('/user')
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log("Data is : ",data);
},
(ex) => {
    console.log('Found exception: ', ex);
});
```

Also, if this is in your provider and you want to return the data, you can create a new Observable and return it. If need help, could edit my answer to that also.