# Read data from Firebase and put into an array

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Ionic application with Native Google Maps and Firebase. I want to load multiple markers on a map, and the positions of these markers (latitude and longitude) are in this Firebase structure:

[image: are in this Firebase structure.]

So I created a provider and a function `getPins()` to get these positions:

```
import { ... };

@Injectable()

public arredoresRef:firebase.database.Reference;

export class ArredoresProvider {

    constructor() {
        this.arredoresRef = firebase.database().ref('/local')
    }

    getPins(): firebase.database.Reference {
        return this.arredoresRef.child('/local');
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to put these positions in an array:

```
import { ... };

@IonicPage({ ... })

@Component({ ... })

export class ArredoresPage {

    constructor( ... ) { ... }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.arredoresProvider.getPins().on('value', snapshot => {
            this.pins = [];
            snapshot.forEach( snap => {
                this.pins.push({
                    latitude: snap.val().latitudeLocal,
                    longitude: snap.val().longitudeLocal
                });
                return false
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But it's not working! It's my first time working with Firebase and Ionic, so I'm confused about how Firebase read data.

[This text](https://www.javascripttuts.com/implementing-native-google-maps-in-an-ionic-application/) was really useful to me, but it does not use Firebase data.

Finally, I apologize for my bad english!

Comment: What is it thats not working? Are you not retrieving the pins at all ? Are you just not able to put them in Maps?

Comment: Whats not working? Cab you get the pins and just not put them in the Maps?

Comment: My function is not retrieving data, the array is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the first solution to this:
[Get data from Firebase in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399634/get-data-from-firebase-in-ionic-2/42432587)

Essentially, you have to use the list reference and make sure you call it using the options {enableSnapshot: true}. Moreover, your data in the structure does not have a .latitudeLocal property on it. Instead, you have to go further in the data structure to access these, for example, you could use another .forEach statement.